# appendChild doesn't work correctly in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, modal-dialog, appendchild

I am trying to create a simple Modal window, but IE isn't cooperating. When I call this function in IE, the content appears at the bottom of the page under all content and the overlay image does not appear. Here's the code:

```
function applyOverlay(src)
{
  var my_overlay = document.createElement('div');

  my_overlay.setAttribute('id','myoverlay');
  var doc_height = document.body.scrollHeight;
  my_overlay.setAttribute('style','text-align:center; position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; background-image:url("images/trbg.png"); width:100%; height:'+doc_height+'; z-index:999;');
  my_overlay.innerHTML="<iframe style='background:none;' frameborder=0 height='100%' width='80%' src='"+src+"'><iframe>";
  document.body.appendChild(my_overlay);
}
```

Comment: does it work on firefox?

Comment: How do you know it's the appendChild call that's failing?

Comment: Maybe because you forgot to close the iframe tag properly.

Comment: Works in Firefox. I believe it is a z-index and/or positioning issue. Iframe close tag doesn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is common IE issue. It is irritating, but managable.

If **document.body.appendChild** is executed within the body tag before the body is closed, IE6 will simply not load the page. 7 and 8 will wait until the page is loaded

So, how to approach this issue?

- wait until the body is loaded, using **body.onload**.
- append the element to another element instead of the body tag.

I recommend the second option. Appending elements to another target element will preserve the intended behavior and not change the way you add your elements to the site.

Comment: The function is called via href, therefore the body is loaded completely before it is appended.

Comment: have you tried appending to some other element firstly and then to a body, for example to a div which already exists when the page is fully loaded