# I need to add content at the end of each page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a client, whose website has 108 different php static pages, and we need to add some content at the end of each page. I want to avoid doing this manually. Is there any way I can add a link at the end of each page programmatically by using .htaccess or php?

Its a limited hosting account, no ssl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [auto_append_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-append-file)

Comment: where should I add this? I don't have access to php.ini

Comment: You can place it in your `.htaccess` file. `php_flag auto_append_file filename`

Answer (score 1):

webbiedave's answer looks simple - but what happens when you append the content to...

```
<html>
...
</html>
```

Whether the text is rendered, and how it is rendered will depend very much on the browser. Also, as per the link provided "If the script is terminated with exit(), auto-append will not occur" - while PHP does a good job of cleaning up the resources at exit, it is still good practice to explicitly call exit when the code should terminate.

Although it's still not a generic solution, I'd go with [auto prepend script](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) containing something like:

```
<?php 
register_shutdown_function('add_footer');

function add_footer()
{
  // try loading a javascript to render the required text
  print '<script type="text/javascript" src="/somepath/addfooter.js"></script>' . "\n";
  // and for browsers with js disabled but which will render the text include it inline
  print '<noscript>' . $include_as_static_text_here . '</noscript>';
}
```

(IME a script tag appended after the closing html tag is generally acceptable to most browsers even though the resulting html is not well formed - and in the few cases where it is not, the worst that happens is that the script is ignored).

Then in addfooter.js, [add the content to the end of the body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447188/appendchild-doesnt-work-correctly-in-ie) of the document.

Obviously this will result in the content being sent twice in some cases - solutions to this should be obvious - but I've omitted them for reasons of time and clarity.

Comment: I figured it out. The problem with this is: it won't show to the search engine since its by js. Figured it out though.