# script not loading in IE 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have the following that loads fine in Chrome/Safari/Firefox but won't launch in IE 8.  Any idea on what's wrong?

```
function loadScript() {

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&' +
    'callback=initialize';
document.body.appendChild(script);
}

window.onload = loadScript;
```

Comment: Looks fine to me? What about trying to append to the `<head>` section?

Comment: Do you have any other referenced scripts that possibly override the `window.onload` function? I only ask because script execution order is not guaranteed and if you don't have safegaurds around each area that sets the handler you could be running into a scenario where a different method is being invoked for the event.

Comment: easy test for @QuintinRobinson 's scenario is change your function name to loadScript10381048104()

Comment: it's to load google maps, i'm loading it into a teamsite interwoven page and it loads actually outside of teamsite in IE but doesn't once it's in teamsite.  BUT in Chrome/Firefox/Safari the maps run and and out of teamsite (though load a little funny, but do load)

Comment: http://www.brighamandwomens.org/Patients_Visitors/pcs/rehabilitationservices/mock/overview.aspx that's in teamsite

Comment: this is out of it http://www.brighamandwomens.org/Patients_Visitors/pcs/rehabilitationservices/mock/brigham_overview.html

Comment: Did you try "script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');" instead of "script.type..."?

Comment: @nathanhayfield Not necessarily, what I was getting at is that if any other loaded script sets the `onload` method of the window object then this assignment would be overridden because the order of execution for referenced scripts is not guaranteed. Looking at the site posted I can see that immediately a script on the page hooks into `onload` without any regard to any method that might already be attached `window.onload=onLoadFunctions;` and it is likely that the script that you load overwrites this method. The site appears to reference jQuery, you should consider using `jQuery.ready()`.

Comment: It happens in IE.. Take a look at [this stack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447188/appendchild-doesnt-work-correctly-in-ie)

Answer (score 0):

```
function loadScript() {

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&' +
    'callback="initialize"'; // added quotes around "initialize"
document.body.appendChild(script);
}

window.onload = loadScript;
```